# Extending Math object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extend

Since it's bad practise extending built-in objects directly, I was thinking about creating a local object that extends the global one, e.g. with `$.extend(obj, Math)`. `Math` is an object, however you can't seem to access any of its properties like this:

```
for (obj in Math) {
   console.log(obj);
}
```

Why?

Comment: Extending the *prototypes* of built-in objects is generally seen as bad practice except for shimming/polyfilling. But adding functions to non-prototypes (like `Math`) is pretty innocuous.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why? What if someone else also added something with the same name? Or is it because it's so rare?

Comment: Why is adding to prototypes generally seen as bad practice? Yes, it's conflicts -- both with things other people add, and updates to the specification. For example: Years ago, PrototypeJS added `indexOf` to array instances, using a `==` comparison. Then `indexOf` was added to the specification, but using `===` comparison. So code using PrototypeJS and relying on the old definition would fail with the new definition. It also gets a bad name because prior to ES5, you couldn't add non-enumerable properties to prototypes, so additions like that showed up in place people didn't expect.

Comment: For me *personally*, I don't have a problem with additions prototypes other than `Object.prototype` in *application* code. You're just taking on the burden of ensuring that if a conflict occurs, you deal with it. Doing it in *libraries* is, in my view, a bad idea.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, why "But adding functions to non-prototypes (like Math) is pretty innocuous"?

Comment: It doesn't have the problem of properties showing up on instances, it's much more contained. There is, of course, still the issue of conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're all defined as *non-enumerable*. Almost all built-in properties of the specification-defined objects are non-enumerable. Non-enumerable properties don't show up when you enumerate the properties in the object (via `for-in` or `Object.keys`).

Two ideas for you, though:

1. You can create your object with `Math` as its prototype, like this:

   ```js
    // Create the MyMath object with Math as its prototype
    var MyMath = Object.create(Math);

    // Check that MyMath has a Math function on it
    display(MyMath.floor(2.3));

    // Utility function
    function display(msg) {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + msg + "</p>");
    }
   ```
2. ES5 introduced a new function, [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.4), which can get the names of all properties (both enumerable and non-enumerable) from an object. (And since the prototype of `Math` is `Object.prototype`, you probably do just want the "own" properties.) So you could do this on an ES5-compliant engine:

   ```js
   // Create the MyMath object with all of the own properties on Math
   var MyMath = {};
   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).forEach(function(name) {
       MyMath[name] = Math[name];
   });

   // Check that MyMath has a Math function on it
   display(MyMath.floor(2.3));

   // Utility function
   function display(msg) {
       document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + msg + "</p>");
   }
   ```

Option 1 is probably your better option, not least because the single-argument version of `Object.create` can be shimmed/polyfilled on pre-ES5 engines.